# What is the exact translate of "number of listening"?

Tags: translation

The words I want to translate is that how much a song is listened? Number of listening or number of listened or anything else? the translate of the number how much a song is downloaded would be good.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Times listened** or **number of times listened** would be appropriate. If you want to indicate the number of people who are listening to that song at the moment, you can say **(number of) active listeners**. As for downloads, **(number of) downloads**, **downloaded n times** are widely used.